# Showing apostrophes with JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, apostrophe

I'm having some problems showing apostrophes with JSON.

I allow the user to insert data into my mysql database and when they use an apostrophe (e.g. Rob's table), it will be stored in the mysql database as Rob\'s table.

When I json encode this data it adds a further backslash, so that it will appear when displayed as: rob\'s table. If I strip slashes then I run into problems with line breaks. Does anyone know if there is a way to encode the data without adding a backslash before the apostrophe?

Comment: Please post the relevant code. When you decode the JSON in PHP, it should remove extra escaping backslashes. Likewise when you store it, it should not be stored with the `\\`. The escaping process should escape the quote for db entry, but not actually store it in the table.

Comment: Or, it's just `magic_quotes` as usual...

Comment: @mario Ten years will pass and we'll still be dealing with residual magic_quotes issues on cheap web hosts.

Comment: Why is it stored as `Rob\'s` table in the first place? There shouldn't be a need to add the backslash.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'll get the relevant code up later this evening. I'll look into Magic Quotes as well. Cheers for the help

Comment: Turns out it was magic quotes. Cheers guys.

Answer (score 0):

you could use nl2br() in combination with strip slashes to prevent an issue with line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [stripslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) when you pull text data out of your database. According to [the state machine diagram](http://www.json.org/) on the JSON website, only escaped double-quote characters are allowed, not single-quotes. Single quote characters do not need to be escaped:

Comment: If I am echoing out the data on a website, using stripslashes() works. But what I am doing is encoding an array using json and then displaying it in an app. So it keeps displaying as \' because it's been escaped

Comment: I figured out that if I don't use mysqli_real_escape when inputing my code the apostrophe's work and the line breaks also work. However I'm worried about attacks after removing mysqli_real_escape. Now I'm trying to replace \r\n with <br/> in JSON.